# R: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu, g++

I have worked now for some time on an R project in my office's desktop computer, but need to carry the scripts with me while on travel. I copied everything into my laptop and did some changes to the code. Alas, when trying to compile (following the exact same procedure I was using in my desktop computer), the following error:

```
$ R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source coala
* installing to library ‘/home/my_pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
* installing *source* package ‘coala’ ...
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to /home/my_pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/coala/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/home/my_pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/coala/libs/coala.so':
/home/my_pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/coala/libs/coala.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/my_pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/coala’
* restoring previous ‘/home/my_pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/coala’
```

Both computers have the same Ubuntu but different R version. Also, I have to mention that I am working in two libraries at the same time and that the accompanying library update without problems, which makes this error message more puzzling. I have checked answers that may be related to this question, but can't figure out how to apply their solutions:

[R: error installing packages UBUNTU - Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : unable to load shared object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588083/r-error-installing-packages-ubuntu-error-in-dyn-loadfile-dllpath-dllpath)
[Got message unable to load shared object stats.so when R starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333097/got-message-unable-to-load-shared-object-stats-so-when-r-starts)

Is there a way to solve this problem? Which may be the cause? What is the undefined symbol `_ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz`?

Comment: similar problem here. Solution found:  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2055

Comment: I've had the same error, and it was due to update of `RCurl` package. I just reinstalled it and got rid of the error.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with `rgdal` on Ubuntu. Re-installing the package was enough to getting it working again.

```
$ sudo R
> install.packages("rgdal")
> quit()
$ exit
```

Answer (score 4):

What is `.libPaths()` giving you as the output?

I encountered the same problem using the latest update today (**R 3.3.1 for MacOS X**). My R installation seemed to crash after updating it. My solution was simply to remove the lib directories from the file system and reinstall R:

```
rm -rf /Users/johann/Library/R/3.3/library
sudo rm -rf Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This solution also worked for me on a GNU/Linux system

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the linkage with your g++ stdlib.  Different versions of Ubuntu have different versions of g++ stdlib.  You cant always copy binaries from one to the other.

You may fix this by recompiling R for the laptop, or using the Ubuntu R packages. e.g. http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/r-base

Answer (score -3):

#### On mac

I had this problem on mac and deleting all R packages and reinstalling them solved for me. If you want to do that, here's how to remove them:

1. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>
2. Type terminal and press enter to open terminal. In terminal paste this `open /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library` and press enter. A finder window should open with a lot of folders
3. Each folder matches an installed R package.
4. Delete them all, close RStudio, reopen RStudio and install the packages you need with `install.packages("dplyr")` etc

#### On GitHub Action

I got this error in a GitHub Action:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/runner/work/_temp/Library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
```

It was because I was using an outdated version of ubuntu. I changed to `ubuntu-latest` and the problem went away. (as a guide, I used dplyr's [workflow](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/.github/workflows/R-CMD-check.yaml)).

Comment: This will delete every package you've ever download in R

Comment: @DanielFreeman that’s the point. Installing them again solved for me.

Comment: This is not the kind of solution people are looking for.