# Load failed for ‘RCurl’ in dyn.load: unable to load shared object - Rstudio - openSuse

Tags: r, rcurl

I'm having problem installing "Rcurl" in Rstudio on opensuse 15.2. I have installed Rstudio from the OS repository, I have been searching for similar questions and answers, and found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588083/r-error-installing-packages-ubuntu-error-in-dyn-loadfile-dllpath-dllpath) which I think it's the closest one to mine but in Ubuntu. Following some suggestions I didn't get to solve the problem in my case. Here is the error I get:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RCurl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/alcides/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpKXseTK/downloaded_packages’
```

This is my session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the error and at first I couldn't install RCurl. The way I solved is by installing:
`sudo zypper install libcurl-devel`
And then from R
`install.packages ("RCurl")`
Among the packages available for Leap 15.2 is also [R-RCurl-1.95_4.11-lp152.6.7.x86_64.rpm](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/R:/released/openSUSE_Leap_15.2/x86_64/), but it is for R 4.0.2, not 3.5 like the one you use.

Comment: I tried the R-RCurl-1.95 mentioned with R 3.5, but didn't work. So I updated R to version 4.0.2 and then try installing the R-RCurl-1.95. It then ask me for a R-bitops dependency, the one that comes with the YAST software management didn't work. The [R-bitops-1.0_6-lp152.7.4.x86_64.rpm](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/R:/released/openSUSE_Leap_15.2/x86_64/) was the one that worked for me. I tested on openSuse Leap 15.2 and 15.1 both with R 4.0.2. Thank you @ruben-diaz